# Is blocking with iptables slow?

Tags: iptables

I have been blocking all Tor nodes with the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j DROP
```

I believe there are about 1,700 IPs block like this.

I have read that blocking using this command can be slow. Is this true and if so, what is a better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg51895.html) to Jan Engelhardt (one of active person in kernel packaging  in OpenSUSE community):

> The theoretical upper limit of maximum number of rules for a 32-bit
>   environment would be somewhere around 38 million

but the real bottleneck with huge rules it is memory. You need to monitor memory `/proc/vmalloc` when you applying such rules to avoid swapping that will slow down computer a lot.

As already was mentioned [IPSet](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) is good to manage such excessive blocking rules, you can assign new rules and delete previously assigned in effective way like:

```
# Create the new set and add the entries to it
ipset -N new-set ....
ipset -A new-set ....
...
# Swap the old and new sets
ipset -W old-set new-set
# Get rid of the old set, which is now under new-set
ipset -X new-set
```

Answer (score 3):

It is slowish, it may be ok on your hardware for your set of rules.  The better alternative would be to use an ipset and an iptables rule that references the set.  [Ipsets](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) stores addresses and networks in a efficient data structure that is a lot faster to search through for a match compared to the base netfilter processing.